# How to edit row without adding another row in tableview in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am showing all address in firstVC Tableview from JSON.. the same addresses i am showing in secondVC tableview here i have an option edit.. so if i click editBtn i am able to send the address to nextVC map.. in nextVC if i continue i am going to finalVC then here i am getting address, here the edited address i need to show in the same row where i click editBtn.. how to do that?

**like below i am sending address to nextVC**: when i click editBtn in Tableview like below i am sending address to nextVC(which i want to edit)

```
func btnEditTapped(cell: EditAddressTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = self.addeditTableview.indexPath(for: cell){
        print("edit button address index \(indexPath.row)")
          let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddressViewController") as! AddressViewController
        viewController.isEdit = true
        var addrLo = addressArray[indexPath.row]

        print("in edit total mode address \(addrLo.pincode)")
        viewController.editPincode = addrLo.pincode
        viewController.editStree = addrLo.streetName
        viewController.editColony = addrLo.colony
        viewController.editCity = addrLo.city
        
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**this is finalVC. code**:  here if i push to FirstViewController then the row should be edited with new address but i am here adding one more.. edit is not working for me

```
 func editAddressService(){
   
let locations: [String: Any] = ["longitude": logitude as Any,"latitude": latitude as Any]

    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                        "pincode": zipName,
                        "city": localityName,
                        "streetName": sublocalityName,
                        "colony": "",
                        "location" : locations,
                        "addressName" : addressTextfield.text
                    ]
        let string = "http://jcksdjfksdljfklsdl"

        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: string)
        let saveAddrsID: String = addAddrsID ?? ""
    print("didload saved address userde edit service \(saveAddrsID)")

        let requestedUserType = URLQueryItem(name: "requestedUserType", value: "personal")

        let requestedItem = URLQueryItem(name: "addressType", value: "Other")

    let requestedItemAddr = URLQueryItem(name: "addressId", value: saveAddrsID)
    
    print("edit addressid \(requestedItemAddr)")

    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
    print(jsonString)
    
        urlComponents?.queryItems = [requestedItem, requestedUserType, requestedItemAddr]
        let urlStr = urlComponents?.url

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlStr!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postData = String(format: "addressdetails=%@",jsonString) .data(using: .utf8)
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
                    do {
                        let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: Any]


                        self.editAddrsID = jsonObject["addressId"] as? String    
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
                            
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                        }
                        
                    } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
                } else {
                }
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

to know flow i have added only this post related code in github: https://github.com/SwiftSamples/AddressEdit

in my github project flow will be: `(profileVC showing all address from JSON) add/edit btn - > (addeditVC showing same profileVC address), editBtn - > profileAddressVC Map continueBtn - > ZoomMapVC(picked address need to show in edit btn index row in profile&addeditVC)`

please help me with code to edit address.

**for edit and add: this is the difference in `/saveaddress/` API**

[image]

Comment: anyone please suggest me some code here

Comment: Took a look at your code on GitHub and I see an number of crashes and issues. My suggestion, you need to determine what your source of truth is? For instance, I see in the `NewZooomAddressViewController` you have a `saveaddAddressService` once the user creates a new address. The value is written to some external source (POST method). I think that should be your single source of truth. So After the user adds a new address, when you come back to the firstVC, you should re-fetch the values from your API. This will help avoid a lot of headache/bugs in the future.

Comment: @TheAppMentor can u let me know where u hit with crash.. so i will fix and update

Comment: @swiftDev make one property and pass edited address from editvc to finalvc or in model make one variable edited address and store value in it while typing and user this model in finalvc

Answer (score 0):

- save indexPath from secondVC
- pass it to finalVC
- get the cell already in finalVC using the saved indexPath

sorting and number of cells must of course be the same in secondVC and finalVC